# Download jQuery script to localize datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to use jQuery datepicker localize in our MVC project, but I can't find languages js files as [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#localization) explain we need some file like this: jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js but the only link I can find is [this](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/i18n/) and we are in Iran can't access to that, is there any link to download languages js files?, also I need Persian (Farsi) version, something like this: jquery.ui.datepicker-fa.js

Comment: for other languages or for updates you can always check the repo on github: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

French:

```
/* French initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Written by Keith Wood (kbwood{at}iinet.com.au) and Stéphane Nahmani (sholby@sholby.net). */
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: '&#x3c;Préc',
        nextText: 'Suiv&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'Courant',
        monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
        'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fév','Mar','Avr','Mai','Jun',
        'Jul','Aoû','Sep','Oct','Nov','Déc'],
        dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dim','Lun','Mar','Mer','Jeu','Ven','Sam'],
        dayNamesMin: ['Di','Lu','Ma','Me','Je','Ve','Sa'],
        weekHeader: 'Sm',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
});
```

Farsi:

```
/* Persian (Farsi) Translation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Javad Mowlanezhad -- jmowla@gmail.com */
/* Jalali calendar should supported soon! (Its implemented but I have to test it) */
jQuery(function($) {
    $.datepicker.regional['fa'] = {
        closeText: 'بستن',
        prevText: '&#x3c;قبلي',
        nextText: 'بعدي&#x3e;',
        currentText: 'امروز',
        monthNames: ['فروردين','ارديبهشت','خرداد','تير','مرداد','شهريور',
        'مهر','آبان','آذر','دي','بهمن','اسفند'],
        monthNamesShort: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
        dayNames: ['يکشنبه','دوشنبه','سه‌شنبه','چهارشنبه','پنجشنبه','جمعه','شنبه'],
        dayNamesShort: ['ي','د','س','چ','پ','ج', 'ش'],
        dayNamesMin: ['ي','د','س','چ','پ','ج', 'ش'],
        weekHeader: 'هف',
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        firstDay: 6,
        isRTL: true,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fa']);
});
```

Simply add them seperately to files and name them as required and everything will work out fine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use http://www.prosoftnearshore.com/blog/post/2011/10/31/Localizing-files-%28jpg-css-js-etc%29-in-ASPNET.aspx to localize the .js files for your specific cultures in combination with [EvilP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9513690/908607)'s answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer saved my credibility today. Thought I'd give back. Here is a Brazilian Portuguese version to those in need.

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['br'] = {
        closeText: 'close',
        prevText: 'Prev',
        nextText: 'Next',
        currentText: 'Current',
        monthNames: ['Janeiro','Fevereiro','Marco','Abril','Maio','Junho','Julho','Agosto','Setembro','Outubro','Novembro','Dezembro'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Jan','Fev','Mar','Abr','Mai','Jun','Jul','Ago','Set','Out','Nov','Dez'],
        dayNames: ['Domingo','Segunda-feira','Terça-feira','Quarta-feira','Quinta-feira','Sexta-feira','Sábado'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Seg','Ter','Qua','Qui','Sex','Sab'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','S','T','Q','Q','S','S'],
        weekHeader: 'D',
        dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['br']);
});
```